# Android emulator system images and AMD processor

Tags: android, android-emulator, arm, mips, intel

I use AMD FX X6 6300 type processor. (it supports virtualization and my BIOS setting is ON)
I installed "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator". When I tried to run Intel accelerator setup, I get that setup is unable to install. (error was virtualization)

SDK Manager has these system images options:
  Android 4.2.2

- Intel x86 Atom System Image
- ARM EABI v7a System Image
- MIPS System Image

So does it make sense to download Intel x86 system image ? Or is it useless without installing HAXM ?

Should I download ARM or MIPS images ? What would you recommend for emulator system images for an AMD processor ?

Or the only option is using snapshots?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) for the emulator, the x86 image specifically requires an Intel processor. When they say:

> ...Virtual machine acceleration for Windows requires the installation of the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel HAXM). The software requires an Intel CPU with Virtualization Technology (VT) support...

They are referring not just to supporting "Virtualization", but to a specific set of [processor extensions](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology) only available on recent Intel processors.

Use the ARM system image. It will get the job done, it just won't feel like you are running a native Android system.

Comment: This is not only not a solution, you contradict the documentation you link to: they support "AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)" - luckily most Android-linux developers will probably be on Linux machines.

Comment: The question was "Should I download ARM or MIPS images?", to which my answer was "Use the ARM system image." Intel HAXM does not support Linux, or AMD processors. If you believe "switch operating systems" is a better answer, feel free to post it.

Comment: Hmm. actually Trante didn't mention what OS was in use - After suffering through the awfully slow emulated Android hardware, I would highly recommend using the Intel one with acceleration personally - that option does work well on Ubuntu 14.04 at least.

Answer (score 10):

As mentionned, HAXM won't work on non-intel CPUs.
So the X86 image won't be any faster than the ARM one (at least, in my experience on an AMD Phenom X6.)

An speedier alternative is to use [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

- It is free for personal use
- An order of magnitude faster than the built-in android emulator.
- It integrates nicely with ADT (Eclipse) once you follow the [detailed user guide](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#collapse8)

Comment: Could not get it to run as Android Studio plugin on a Linux box with Phenom II processor.   Gave up on emulation.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into the same problem with after Windows 10 **October update (1809)** with my AMD Ryzen 7 2700 CPU.
There is the full solution tested on **3-Oct-2018**:

1. Get latest Windows 10 update. (*You can check your windows version by right click the left bottom corner window button, then select `System`*) Currently, the October update (1809) won't download automatically, you have to download from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
2. Search **"Turn windows features on or off"**, and check the **"Windows Hypervisor Platform"** (*this option only appears when your Windows on* **version 1803 or higher**)
3. **IMPORTANT**: Turn on **AMD SVM**! This option should be in somewhere under your **BIOS** menu. **If your motherboard doesn't support AMD SVM, don't waste time, your computer doesn't support hardware acceleration for now.**

   For my Gigabyte B450 Aorus PRO Wifi with BIOS version F2, it's under:

   Restart computer, click "Delete" button to open BISO menu, `M.I.T. -> Advanced Frequency Settings -> Advanced CPU Core Settings -> SVM mode -> Enabled` (This varied based on different motherboard manufactures)
4. Check your Android Studio version. The latest stable version works (3.2.1 when written)
5. Check your Android Emulator version. The latest stable version works (28.0.16 when written)

Now you should able to create a virtual device with a recommended system image, `Oreo 27 x86 Android 8.1 (Google Play)` works.

Under "Verify Configuration", you will see "Emulated Performance" -> "Graphics" is set to "Automatic" and cannot be changed, but it's OK, you emulator should still run.

If you like to use graphics hardware acceleration (`Hardware - GLES 2.0`), go to `x86 Images`, and select an `ABI` with `x86_64` architecture.

**NOTE:** Do **NOT** install "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)". The installation will fail, and you don't need it for AMD CPU at all!

Answer (score 1):

Android Emulator - AMD Processor & Hyper-V Support in Windows 10.

You need the following setup requirements to be in place:

```
1. Android Emulator v27.3.8+ - download via Android Studio SDK Manager.
2. x86 Android Virtual Device (AVD) - Create AVD. 
3. Windows 10 Update.
4. Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform"
```

[Select - Windows Hypervisor platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiXTe.png)

**Note**: Enable via Windows Features: "Hyper-V" - Only available for Windows 10 Professional/Education/Enterprise