# Android_AVD_Startup_Issues

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've installed the necessary components for API 19 including Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) but still it doesn't starts and posts the error: Emulation currently requires Hardware Acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable. CPU Acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed. My Hardware Specs: AMD A8, HP ENVY Quad Core. Is this because of AMD Processor?
You can find the images on (1): https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=56829C722C837939!11336&authkey=!AM19hzHyH5mjwSw&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

(2): https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=56829C722C837939!11337&authkey=!ABUKaiVxf262KMA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: HAXM works on Intel processors, not AMD. Use ARM system image instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android emulator system images and AMD processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817118/android-emulator-system-images-and-amd-processor)

Answer (score 1):

From Android dev [site](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html):

> Virtual machine acceleration for Windows requires the installation of the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel HAXM). **The
>   software requires an Intel CPU** with Virtualization Technology (VT)
>   support and one of the following operating systems:
>
> Windows 7 (32/64-bit) 
>   Windows Vista (32/64-bit) 
>   Windows XP (32-bit only)

So yes, you cant use Intel HAXM unless you use Intel processor.