# Can not start android Emulator from AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

While starting Emulator from AVD Manager, I am getting following error

Starting emulator for AVD 'Demo'
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

So I download the **intelhaxm-android.exe** and try to install it.

But I am getting the following error

This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

I am using Windows 7 (32-bit) with following Processor

AMD Athlon(tm) II Dual-core M300 2.0GHz

Drive has ~7 GB free space

Please help me for this,

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android emulator system images and AMD processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817118/android-emulator-system-images-and-amd-processor)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intel's HAXM equivalent for AMD on Windows OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os)

Comment: Thanks everyone,

I found the solution on [Here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817118/android-emulator-system-images-and-amd-processor

Answer (score 0):

Intel HAXM only works with Intel processors that have VT capabilities. You will need to try another type of emulator like Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

Intel HAXM only works with Intel processors that have support for Intel Virtualization Technology. So you need to follow these steps:

Step 1: In menu bar select Tools > Android > AVD Manager
another new popup window will open.

Step 2:
On that window select "Create Virtual Device" from your left bottom corner. Another popup window will open with the title of Configuration of Virtual Device.

Step 3:
Select Phone from (your right) category menu and Press Next button.

Step 4:
Now you'll ask to select system image. Here you need to select **Relaese Name** with **API Level** and important step to remember must select **ABI: armeabi**

(It will only shown to you, if you already downloaded the Android API level from your SDK)
and then press Next.

You are done and you can now easily use the emulator.